# Magento 2.1.7 new theme installation error

Tags: magento-2.1.7

am tried to change new Magento[image] theme. Store - configuration - Design. but design change not showing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Content >  Configuration (Under design)** then select your store and you can change theme there

Comment: Is possible can i import ver 2.0.0 theme to ver 2.1.7 site